mmrm R package : No optimizer led to a successful model fit
I was asked to create a model for repeated mesures using the R package mmrm.
Unfortunately, I get an error when I try to fit my model:
fit <-mmrm(
    formula = value ~  group*VISIT +  us(VISIT | SUBJID),
    data = data_test
)

In VISIT there are dropped visits: WEEK 2, WEEK 3, WEEK 6, WEEK 11,
WEEK 17, WEEK 19 Erreur dans refit_multiple_optimizers(fit = fit,
control = control) :    No optimizer led to a successful model fit.
Please try to use a different covariance structure or other
covariates. 

I have the same error when I try with a simpler model (i.e.
value ~  VISIT +  us(VISIT | SUBJID)

or
value ~  group +  us(VISIT | SUBJID))

Is there a way to resolve this error ?
Otherwise, I just would like to understand why I get it.
Here are my data:



SUBJID
group
VISIT
value




P1
A
WEEK 1
12.5624513


P1
A
WEEK 5
30.2187267


P1
A
WEEK 7
2.6120847


P1
A
WEEK 9
-16.0866668


P1
A
WEEK 13
1.9989708


P1
A
WEEK 16
-12.0143315


P1
A
WEEK 18
-8.8957782


P1
A
WEEK 20
31.8993502


P12
B
WEEK 1
27.2290542


P12
B
WEEK 4
13.1792339


P23
A
WEEK 1
-13.2155991


P23
A
WEEK 5
-21.7129127


P23
A
WEEK 7
2.0031156


P23
A
WEEK 9
-26.2071653


P23
A
WEEK 13
-7.1450728


P23
A
WEEK 16
8.7739081


P34
B
WEEK 1
-10.5046040


P34
B
WEEK 5
-33.7108446


P34
B
WEEK 7
28.8673347


P34
B
WEEK 9
-28.2987619


P34
B
WEEK 13
19.7531785


P34
B
WEEK 16
-12.5672025


P34
B
WEEK 18
23.6605455


P34
B
WEEK 20
-56.4618230


P45
A
WEEK 1
-10.0781255


P45
A
WEEK 5
-14.3044541


P45
A
WEEK 7
26.7420761


P45
A
WEEK 9
-40.3532490


P45
A
WEEK 13
5.9816048


P45
A
WEEK 16
21.5443334


P45
A
WEEK 18
11.0535832


P45
A
WEEK 20
20.5635443


P53
B
WEEK 1
-14.6771797


P53
B
WEEK 5
-11.6853723


P54
B
WEEK 1
25.0652126


P54
B
WEEK 5
26.8911853


P54
B
WEEK 7
-9.3434406


P54
B
WEEK 9
-15.5373768


P54
B
WEEK 13
13.2729042


P54
B
WEEK 16
-0.2099424


P54
B
WEEK 18
26.1054039


P55
B
WEEK 1
2.7942745


P55
B
WEEK 5
8.6644719


P55
B
WEEK 7
2.5585254


P55
B
WEEK 9
-13.7905622


P55
B
WEEK 14
-8.4709933


P56
A
WEEK 1
-26.7274210


P56
A
WEEK 5
1.6878530


P56
A
WEEK 7
-19.7113795


P56
A
WEEK 9
-0.8568246


P56
A
WEEK 13
-3.7184852


P56
A
WEEK 16
18.4346838


P56
A
WEEK 18
20.4545792


P56
A
WEEK 20
-4.3280076


P2
A
WEEK 1
16.4610117


P2
A
WEEK 5
-3.9896513


P2
A
WEEK 7
-10.4784093


P2
A
WEEK 9
1.2297233


P2
A
WEEK 13
-11.2124232


P2
A
WEEK 16
8.0156683


P3
B
WEEK 1
0.3865717


P3
B
WEEK 5
22.6685423


P3
B
WEEK 7
10.4242805


P3
B
WEEK 9
-6.8330206


P3
B
WEEK 13
17.2591860


P4
A
WEEK 1
32.8994574


P4
A
WEEK 5
28.6854162


P4
A
WEEK 7
35.0114736


P4
A
WEEK 9
40.6488041


P4
A
WEEK 13
11.8529362


P5
A
WEEK 1
25.3071328


P5
A
WEEK 5
-18.3119157


P5
A
WEEK 7
-24.8956887


P5
A
WEEK 9
-6.6738302


P5
A
WEEK 13
-21.5909301


P5
A
WEEK 16
-1.2420696


P5
A
WEEK 18
-11.4144868


P5
A
WEEK 20
-4.8247247


P6
B
WEEK 1
3.6336884


P6
B
WEEK 5
-10.4870357


P7
A
WEEK 1
5.3433774


P7
A
WEEK 5
6.6546170


P7
A
WEEK 9
-2.6937276


P8
B
WEEK 1
-9.9484963


P8
B
WEEK 5
-10.4157186


P8
B
WEEK 8
-18.2602490


P9
B
WEEK 1
8.6279078


P9
B
WEEK 5
-3.2827726


P9
B
WEEK 7
20.9898807


P9
B
WEEK 10
11.6516747


P10
B
WEEK 1
22.4885008


P10
B
WEEK 5
-22.9774604


P10
B
WEEK 7
-24.3145152


P10
B
WEEK 9
15.1506204


P10
B
WEEK 20
-2.5799654


P11
A
WEEK 1
-2.8080128


P11
A
WEEK 5
38.3449886


P11
A
WEEK 7
39.1255635


P11
A
WEEK 9
-10.9332045


P11
A
WEEK 16
32.0682584


P13
B
WEEK 1
-22.5737237


P13
B
WEEK 5
-0.3777569


P14
A
WEEK 1
-9.2740263


P14
A
WEEK 5
-26.5408616


P14
A
WEEK 7
-10.3753967


P14
A
WEEK 9
14.9332351


P15
B
WEEK 1
-6.8173154


P15
B
WEEK 5
-4.5930482


P15
B
WEEK 7
21.8489707


P15
B
WEEK 12
10.6311885


P16
A
WEEK 1
5.2112211


P16
A
WEEK 5
-24.8807027


P16
A
WEEK 7
-2.9866771


P16
A
WEEK 9
-17.0100276


P16
A
WEEK 13
-14.6911634


P16
A
WEEK 16
-13.3791804


P16
A
WEEK 18
20.2954169


P16
A
WEEK 20
6.6477472


P17
B
WEEK 1
21.5067430


P17
B
WEEK 5
-6.5135839


P17
B
WEEK 7
40.7285761


P17
B
WEEK 9
-17.0575449


P17
B
WEEK 18
2.1128352


P18
A
WEEK 1
15.4183833


P18
A
WEEK 5
24.1660862


P18
A
WEEK 7
-2.3696210


P18
A
WEEK 9
4.7453568


P18
A
WEEK 16
7.0771887


P19
B
WEEK 1
6.8017227


P19
B
WEEK 5
14.5683651


P19
B
WEEK 7
-9.9995174


P19
B
WEEK 12
-36.7648189


P20
B
WEEK 1
8.8399608


P20
B
WEEK 5
20.5707414


P20
B
WEEK 7
26.7482907


P20
B
WEEK 9
-12.7379550


P20
B
WEEK 13
-27.2381304


P21
A
WEEK 1
7.1996233


P21
A
WEEK 5
-2.0689480


P21
A
WEEK 7
-11.4388347


P21
A
WEEK 9
-5.7972027


P21
A
WEEK 13
-34.9733359


P21
A
WEEK 16
2.3740398


P21
A
WEEK 18
1.9971458


P21
A
WEEK 20
6.2341647


P22
B
WEEK 1
26.7893737


P22
B
WEEK 5
-4.5105179


P22
B
WEEK 10
6.9761514


P24
A
WEEK 1
23.0326696


P24
A
WEEK 5
22.5183315


P24
A
WEEK 7
-13.2851187


P24
A
WEEK 9
-6.5287444


P24
A
WEEK 13
-14.2161505


P24
A
WEEK 16
12.3310377


P25
A
WEEK 1
-53.5384125


P25
A
WEEK 5
25.0277876


P25
A
WEEK 7
1.1619896


P25
A
WEEK 9
-0.9504972


P25
A
WEEK 20
21.7210923


P26
B
WEEK 1
2.8788698


P26
B
WEEK 5
0.7810502


P26
B
WEEK 7
-6.1187801


P26
B
WEEK 9
37.0668581


P26
B
WEEK 13
17.5646520


P26
B
WEEK 16
-11.4086297


P26
B
WEEK 18
0.4243842


P26
B
WEEK 20
-36.5324034


P27
B
WEEK 1
4.3865110


P27
B
WEEK 5
14.8689754


P27
B
WEEK 7
-4.1483733


P27
B
WEEK 15
-10.0514418


P28
B
WEEK 1
6.2192356


P28
B
WEEK 4
-8.6972549


P29
A
WEEK 1
5.0481018


P29
A
WEEK 5
24.9447036


P29
A
WEEK 7
10.0384917


P29
A
WEEK 9
5.2082975


P29
A
WEEK 13
14.7263603


P29
A
WEEK 16
-24.8374113


P29
A
WEEK 18
28.8839421


P29
A
WEEK 20
3.9804703


P30
B
WEEK 1
8.7947073


P30
B
WEEK 5
3.1941859


P30
B
WEEK 7
13.3281743


P30
B
WEEK 9
34.4745830


P30
B
WEEK 13
-24.7549235


P31
A
WEEK 1
15.0479907


P31
A
WEEK 5
14.7733936


P31
A
WEEK 7
9.9485226


P31
A
WEEK 9
-32.4729931


P31
A
WEEK 13
10.0535371


P31
A
WEEK 16
17.6069070


P31
A
WEEK 18
-38.5244162


P31
A
WEEK 20
28.5831392


P32
B
WEEK 1
21.4625574


P32
B
WEEK 5
21.0487005


P32
B
WEEK 8
-3.4362695


P33
A
WEEK 1
21.8531995


P33
A
WEEK 5
9.7897047


P33
A
WEEK 7
29.9562985


P33
A
WEEK 9
21.8946713


P35
A
WEEK 1
-3.9025412


P35
A
WEEK 5
14.2278385


P35
A
WEEK 7
22.2139321


P35
A
WEEK 20
14.5959592


P36
B
WEEK 1
35.5019503


P36
B
WEEK 5
16.7862453


P36
B
WEEK 7
4.6192485


P36
B
WEEK 12
13.7361979


P37
B
WEEK 1
10.6442102


P37
B
WEEK 5
6.1562564


P37
B
WEEK 8
11.1652446


P38
B
WEEK 1
-10.8364586


P38
B
WEEK 5
-10.4484788


P38
B
WEEK 7
-20.6733436


P38
B
WEEK 9
-51.9584141


P39
A
WEEK 1
-12.6347484


P39
A
WEEK 5
11.3764625


P39
A
WEEK 9
0.7094508


P39
A
WEEK 13
9.0516189


P40
B
WEEK 1
7.5605914


P40
B
WEEK 5
22.3138274


P41
B
WEEK 1
-31.7014542


P41
B
WEEK 5
-9.7387074


P42
A
WEEK 1
36.5776801


P42
A
WEEK 5
53.4049333


P42
A
WEEK 7
4.2751025


P42
A
WEEK 9
-43.0932958


P42
A
WEEK 13
37.4938873


P42
A
WEEK 16
9.8790617


P43
A
WEEK 1
12.0672504


P43
A
WEEK 5
15.7464630


P43
A
WEEK 9
-6.0168558


P43
A
WEEK 13
-26.7593459


P43
A
WEEK 16
-17.8923509


P43
A
WEEK 18
-40.4076295


P43
A
WEEK 20
9.3701524


P44
B
WEEK 1
2.6896738


P44
B
WEEK 5
-17.7326657


P44
B
WEEK 7
-8.4684519


P44
B
WEEK 9
27.9086804


P44
B
WEEK 13
22.3094316


P44
B
WEEK 16
-27.2006753


P44
B
WEEK 18
18.1266052


P46
B
WEEK 1
-0.0867470


P46
B
WEEK 5
3.6611948


P46
B
WEEK 7
17.2142066


P47
B
WEEK 1
25.8626416


P47
B
WEEK 5
52.6702267


P47
B
WEEK 7
20.1786452


P47
B
WEEK 9
4.7949483


P47
B
WEEK 18
14.8760757


P48
A
WEEK 1
-0.9294240


P48
A
WEEK 5
24.9356875


P48
A
WEEK 7
-29.7941653


P48
A
WEEK 9
7.1204398


P48
A
WEEK 13
-9.6192826


P48
A
WEEK 16
46.7073001


P49
A
WEEK 1
28.2173913


P49
A
WEEK 5
-27.0843482


P49
A
WEEK 7
0.4547160


P49
A
WEEK 9
-2.6501748


P50
A
WEEK 1
-14.1758514


P50
A
WEEK 5
-39.2558318


P50
A
WEEK 7
5.5419297


P50
A
WEEK 9
-13.6592348


P50
A
WEEK 13
54.1506063


P50
A
WEEK 16
18.6291710


P50
A
WEEK 18
15.4282588


P50
A
WEEK 20
29.9047959


P51
A
WEEK 1
19.4158757


P51
A
WEEK 5
0.4875712


P51
A
WEEK 9
4.2146024


P52
A
WEEK 1
-19.9565398


P52
A
WEEK 5
-30.7055229


P52
A
WEEK 7
44.0418956


P52
A
WEEK 9
13.9048741


P52
A
WEEK 13
1.3513905




Recall that a mixed model for repeated measures fits a multivariate normal distribution to your outcome $\mathbf{y}$, with quite some options for its covariance structure $\mathbf{V}$. In your case you have 14 unique visits, so $\mathbf{y}$ is a vector with 14 elements and $\mathbf{V}$ is a 14x14 matrix. In particular, your unstructured $\mathbf{V}$ will contain 105 unique parameters.
The problem is that not all of your visits have many, or even multiple observations:



Week
N




1
56


4
2


5
54


7
41


8
3


9
38


10
2


12
3


13
25


14
1


15
1


..
..



These visits with few observations have far too little information to fit such an extensive covariance structure to. If you were to consider for example a very simple compound symmetric structure (2 parameters; one variance and one covariance), the model will run fine.
I would not recommend you simplify your covariance structure so much however, there are some other options:

try increasingly simple structures until you find one that works (Toeplitz [14 parameters] seems to be borderline, heterogeneous first-order auto-regressive [15 parameters] gives no optimizer warnings)
omit the sparse visits (lose a bit of data)
pool them with a nearby dense visit (lose a bit of precision in time)

Either of the last two should let you fit the interaction model with an unstructured $\mathbf{V}$.

Another solution if you really want to fit an unstructured covariance matrix is to fit a Bayesian model with a prior on the covariance matrix that gives higher prior probability to correlations close to zero.

By the way this is overall a great answer because it focuses on the broader point that if you are "fishing" through optimizers trying to find one that converges, and none of them work, it is a sign that your model is overspecified and there isn't enough information in the data to estimate the parameters. Thus you have to simplify the model or simplify the data so that fewer parameters need to be estimated. As @PBulls suggests, the ideal way to do this is "little by little."

Nice answer @PBulls (+1) :)

Yes, thank you very much @PBulls
